# Spring Integration - send form parameters of type "application/x-www-form-urlencoded" using http-outbound gateway (POST)

Tags: spring-integration, spring-integration-dsl, spring-integration-http

Technologies I am using 
    Spring Boot 2.x, 
    Spring Integration 5.x.

I am trying to send form parameters using http-outbound gateway (POST).
My spring-integration file looks like

```
<int-http:inbound-gateway id="lpaGateway"
                              request-channel="myGatewayRequests"
                              supported-methods="POST"
                              path="/test"
                              request-payload-type="java.lang.String"
                              reply-timeout="180000"
                              reply-channel="myGatewayResponses"
                              error-channel="httpErrorChannel">

        <int-http:request-mapping consumes="application/xml" produces="application/xml"/>
</int-http:inbound-gateway>    

<!-- Transformer to generate OAuth request payload  -->
<int:transformer input-channel="oAuthRequestGeneration"
                     ref="myTransformer"
                     method="oAuthRequestPayloadGenerator"
                     output-channel="oAuthRequests"/>

<int:chain input-channel="oAuthRequests" output-channel="oAuthResponses">
        <int:header-enricher>
            <int:header name="Content-Type" value="application/x-www-form-urlencoded"/>
        </int:header-enricher>
        <int:transformer expression="payload.getoAuthRequestCredentialsMap()"/>
    <int-http:outbound-gateway id="lpaPostGateway"
                                   url="${oauth_endpoint}"
                                   http-method="POST"
                                   extract-request-payload="true"
                                   expected-response-type="java.lang.String"
                                   header-mapper="headerMapper">
         <!-- <int-http:uri-variable name="request" expression="payload"/> -->
    </int-http:outbound-gateway>
</int:chain>
```

In my transformer I am creating a Map of my form parameters as shown below and setting that map into my payload.

```
public MultiValueMap<String, String> oAuthRequestCredentialsMap(){

        MultiValueMap<String, String> oAuthRequestCredentialsMap = new LinkedMultiValueMap<>();

        oAuthRequestCredentialsMap.add("username", username);
        oAuthRequestCredentialsMap.add("password", password);

        return oAuthRequestCredentialsMap;
    }
```

When hitting the POST URL, I am getting the following exception.

```
org.springframework.messaging.MessageHandlingException: HTTP request execution failed for URI [myUrl]; nested exception is org.springframework.web.client.HttpClientErrorException$Unauthorized: 401 Unauthorized - Bad Token, failedMessage=GenericMessage [payload={username=[username], password=[password]}, headers={content-length=93387, http_requestMethod=POST, errorChannel=org.springframework.messaging.core.GenericMessagingTemplate$TemporaryReplyChannel@14b2c481, cookie=JSESSIONID=633EAA21C082C31AD527CBA0258A7532, pollingFrequency=0, accept=*/*, authorization=Basic aW50Z0xha2V3b29kRnJlZGRpZU1hYzpVdG02dTVLdFQ1c2VYeHBO, replyChannel=org.springframework.messaging.core
```

- From my understanding, client cannot read the the form parameters that I am sending as a map, returning with 401 - Unauthorized - Bad token. I have checked all the credentials, nothing wrong with them. Its just that the client is not able to read them.
- The response that I get is json, whether it is a success or failure. When getting an exception in my error-channel, i am trying read the body but it is returning null. This is how I am trying to read the exception.

```
MessagingException messagingException = messagingExceptionMessage.getPayload();
HttpStatusCodeException httpStatusCodeException = (HttpStatusCodeException) messagingException.getCause();
String httpResponseBody = httpStatusCodeException.getResponseBodyAsString();
```